# Google OAuth tokens stop working after a period (iOS 7 app)

Tags: ios, oauth, youtube

so I have an application that requires accessing data form google using OAuth2. I have methods to refresh the data stored and add new accounts into the application. I've been testing using two accounts. I have no problem signing in with one account, and refreshing with that one account is fine (to begin with). I have no problem signing my second account in simultaneously and refreshing both sets of data together. However, after a prolonged period of absence I come back and try to refresh either with one or both accounts and it crashes. From my Logs I've inferred that the tokens are no longer any good and that the server has stopped giving me back any data. Every time I send a request I first refresh my access tokens using my refresh tokens, which are saved in the phone memory.

**Q1: Have I evaluated the problem correctly, i.e. is there something wrong with my tokens?**

Q2: Do Refresh tokens expire after a given period?

if yes Q3: What do I do to get past this problem?

Here is a section of my code, from the token refresh to the data request:

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"client_id=%@&client_secret=%@&refresh_token=%@&grant_type=refresh_token", mAuth.clientID, mAuth.clientSecret, [self.defaults objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"refresh_token %i", i]]];
NSLog(@"AT - %@", [self.defaults objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"access_token %i", i]]);
NSLog(@"TT - %@", [self.defaults objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"token_type %i", i]]);
NSLog(@"ET - %@", [self.defaults objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"expires_in %i", i]]);
NSLog(@"RT - %@", [self.defaults objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"refresh_token %i", i]]);
NSLog(@"%@", post);
NSMutableData *postData = [NSMutableData data];
[postData appendData:[post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"]]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
NSData *connection = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *tokenString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:connection encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", tokenString);
[self complexParseFromString:tokenString forInt:i];
NSLog(@"AT - %@", [self.defaults objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"access_token %i", i]]);
NSLog(@"TT - %@", [self.defaults objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"token_type %i", i]]);
NSLog(@"ET - %@", [self.defaults objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"expires_in %i", i]]);
NSLog(@"RT - %@", [self.defaults objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"refresh_token %i", i]]);
NSMutableURLRequest *GETRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&mine=true"]]];
[GETRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[GETRequest setValue:@"www.googleapis.com" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Host"];
[GETRequest setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", [self.defaults objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"access_token %i", i]]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
connection = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:GETRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
responderString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:connection encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
arrayChannel = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[self simpleParseFromString:responderString]];
GETRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=contentDetails&playlistId=%@", [arrayChannel objectAtIndex:[arrayChannel indexOfObject:@"uploads"] + 1]]]];
[GETRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[GETRequest setValue:@"www.googleapis.com" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Host"];
[GETRequest setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", [self.defaults objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"access_token %i", i]]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
connection = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:GETRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
responderString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:connection encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

Per https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ForDevices

"Access tokens have a *limited lifetime*. If your application needs access to an API over a long period of time, then it can use the refresh token to obtain a new access token (see Using a refresh token). If your application needs this type of access, then it should store the refresh token for later use."

Note: For Google, refresh tokens do not expire. However, I've see oauth providers that expire refresh tokens as well. AFAIK the spec doesn't specify.